# How to only audit [Audited] methods without having [DisabledAudited] everywhere?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

My Audit logs are getting out of hand so I decided I want to only audit all requests which basically are not a `Get` request. Is there a very simply way to do this from configuration?

The documentation here:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging

Says:

> Note: In addition to the standard audit configuration, MVC and ASP.NET
> Core modules define configurations to enable/disable audit logging for
> actions.

But I could not find more information about what exactly this means.

As a last resort, I know it would work if I went to every class and added `[DisableAuditing]` and then  `[Audited]` on the non-Get endpoints, but that seems a bit messy.

Best soltuion: I just want to have a simply way to select only non-`GET` requests and audit them.

Second best solution:
I just want to have only `[Audited]` methods audited. I don't want to have to go and write `[DisabledAuditing]` on every class.

Comment: @BehzadShirani No it seems I never solved this, I just accepted that my logs will get too big. It is still a problem to be honest, most likely I should just restrict searching to the last X days of log data.

Comment: Could create a background job worker that deletes rows older than X time in the table, might be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `AuditStore` to do that, and then replace the original AuditStore in service `YourAplicationNameCoreModule`

Here is the example

```
public class YourAuditStore : AuditingStore
{

    public ILogger<AuditingStore> Logger { get; set; }

    private readonly IRepository<AuditLog, long> _auditLogRepository;
    private readonly ISettingManager _settingManager;

    public YourAuditStore(IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository, ISettingManager settingManager) : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
        _auditLogRepository = auditLogRepository;
        _settingManager = settingManager;
    }

    public override async Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        AuditLog auditLog = new AuditLog();

        bool logErrorsOnly = await _settingManager.GetSettingValueAsync<bool>(AppSettings.Logging.LogOnErrorsOnly);

        var exceptionMessage = auditInfo.Exception != null ? auditInfo.Exception.ToString() : null;

        if ((logErrorsOnly && exceptionMessage != null) || !logErrorsOnly)
        {

            auditLog = await _auditLogRepository.InsertAsync(AuditLog.CreateFromAuditInfo(auditInfo));
        }


    }

}
```

As you can see, you can filter whatever you want in `SaveAsync` method as it recieve the `AuditInfo`,  you can check if method is different to `Get` then save

Add the next code to `YourApplicationNameCoreModule` on `PreInitialize` method

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
   Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuditingStore, YourAuditStore>();
}
```

Comment: your answer is to log only errors or exceptions. but how to Audit only desired normal methods?

Comment: The `AuditInfo` class has a `MethodName` property in this AuditStore you can filter for specific methods using this property and check if there was an exception too with `Exception` propery on the same class.

Comment: Do you mean hard-code all the desired methods?